# Why does this Python code print nothing?

Tags: python

```
class a(str):
    def b(self,*x,**y):
        print str.decode(self,*x,**y)

b=a()
b.b('utf-8','aaa') # This prints nothing, why?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try initialize your string first, with some value:

```
# classes should have capitalized names ...
class a(str):
    def b(self,*x,**y):
        print 'debugging: ', self, x, y
        print str.decode(self, *x,**y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b=a('aaa')
    b.b('utf-8')

    b=a()
    b.b('utf-8')

# => output

# debugging:  aaa ('utf-8',) {}
# aaa
# debugging:   ('utf-8',) {}
#
```

Answer (score 4):

because you initialize b (as an object of a) with nothing as str.

Comment: Very confusing answer, especially given the multiple occurrences of "b".  I think you meant to say "as an instance of a", and possibly "with an empty string as the initial value" or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

Try printing (self,x,y). You will see

```
('', ('utf-8', 'aaa'), {})
```

Therefore, in `str.decode(self,*x,**y)`, `self` is acting as the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

When you initiate `b1 = a()`, it's almost the same as `b2 = str()` except that `b2` doesn't have the `bound method` `b()` of class `a`. Hence, when you invoke `b1.b(...)`, it's the same as calling `print str.decode(b1,...)` or `print str.decode(b2, ...)`

`b1` and `b2` are the same in the way that they are both empty strings. Now take a look at what docs say about `str.decode`.

> decode(...)
>       S.decode([encoding[**,errors**]]) -> object
>
> ```
> Decodes S using the codec registered for encoding. encoding defaults
> to the default encoding. **errors** may be given to set a different error
> handling scheme. Default is 'strict' meaning that encoding errors raise
> a UnicodeDecodeError. Other possible values are 'ignore' and 'replace'
> as well as any other name registerd with codecs.register_error that is
> able to handle UnicodeDecodeErrors.
> ```

That means the third parameter (actually the second in the context of `bound method`) is a sort of error type which would be ignored if it doesn't match any builtin (registered) type.

So when you call `b1.b('utf-8', 'abc')` which will be corresponding to `b1.b([encoding], [error type])`. Python will translate it to `print str.decode(b1, [encoding], [error type])`. Since `b1` is empty and your "error type" which is `'abc'` doesn't match any registered error type, python just prints out an empty string and ignores the given "error type."

If you try `b = a('hello')` and `b.b('utf-8', 'abc')`, you will see that the output is `hello` and there is nothing to do with `'abc'`. Moreover, if you try to provide one more parameter such as `b.b('utf-8', 'abc', 'xyz')`, python will raise an error since `str.decode()` only accepts up to two arguments in the context of `bound method`.